# RSS feed from Blogspot as desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows-7, rss, desktop-customization

I'd like to use the images from this [blogspot RSS feed](http://nuthinbutmech.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss) as a desktop wallpaper source.

I've tried using the Windows 7 built-in system, as well as John's Background Switcher. The Windows 7 thing appears to do nothing. When I test the URL with John's Background Switcher it says 'there don't appear to be any pictures within the actual feed'.

I guess there's some redirection step that Windows 7 and John's Background Switcher can't do. Is there some web service that could help out here?

Answer (score -1):

The windows background expects the picture to be in a selection of picture formats, jpg, bmp, png, gif etc. Setting it as an updating or scrolling feed is why you are getting the error as the feed will be in text and not picture format.

Best way to get around it is to install an RSS feed system on your computer, use outlook if you have to but there are plenty of free RSS feed window programs out there to play with. Im afraid having it as a background would cause some major problems. If you want the window to be see through make sure you can set the feed player to have transparent background.

This is advice and should be taken as such.

Comment: Thanks - I want to pull the images from the feed, which googling tells me should be supported by John's Background Switcher, if not Windows 7 internally.

Comment: Win7 does support RSS feeds for wallpaper, but as Long Zheng [notes](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090126/rss-powered-windows-7-desktop-slideshows/), "Images must be an enclosure item in the feed for the slideshow to work."